# How do I put webpages in html frames and separate the individual frames from each other?

Tags: html

My assignment is to write an html document with 3 rows and 4 columns. It needs to include a message for browsers that don't support frames. the frames need to have a webpage in each one. each frame needs to be separated and have a border. this is what I have so far.. Please help its due tonight, what am I doing wrong?

[My code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgwFk.png)

Comment: can you edit the question and post the code here? I do see frameset but be advised that is outdated. It doesn't work in HTML5.You can use iframe

Comment: somebody is wasting your time with that assignement - framesets are outdated technology, there is no reason at all to still use them...

Answer (score 0):

If you are relatively new the first thing is to use a framework it makes life a little easier especially with layout.

The best choice in my opinion is bootstrap:

http://getbootstrap.com/

In boostrap you can do a layout of 3 rows x 4 cols as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><iframe></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><iframe></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><iframe></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><iframe></div>
</div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><iframe></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><iframe></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><iframe></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><iframe></div>
</div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"><iframe></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><iframe></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><iframe></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><iframe></div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to boostrap that discusses layout using rows and cols

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

You would do best to fix each iframes height by addings css like this

```
iframe {
  height: 400px;
}
```

Showing the message when iframes are not supported you have covered in your existing code. You just need to mark up each iframe and a bit of CSS.